# Последовательное выполнение тестовых групп

Tags: java, testng

Созданы методы:

```
@BeforeGroups(groups = {"INdependent"})
@BeforeGroups(groups = {"dependent"})
@Test (groups = {"INdependent"})
@Test (groups = {"dependent"}, dependsOnGroups = {"INdependent"})
@AfterMethod(groups = {"INdependent"})
@AfterMethod(groups = {"dependent"})
@AfterGroups(groups = {"INdependent"})
@AfterGroups(groups = {"dependent"})
```

Ожидаю следующую последовательность выполнения кода:

```
BeforeGroups = "INdependent"
  Test = "INdependent"
  AfterMethod = "INdependent"
AfterGroups = "INdependent"
BeforeGroups = "dependent"
  Test = "dependent"
  AfterMethod = "dependent"
AfterGroups = "dependent"
```

Фактически же выполняется так:

```
BeforeGroups = "INdependent"
  Test = "INdependent"
  AfterMethod = "dependent"     (этого тут быть не должно)
  AfterMethod = "INdependent"
AfterGroups = "INdependent"
BeforeGroups = "dependent"
  Test = "dependent"
  AfterMethod = "dependent"
  AfterMethod = "INdependent"   (этого тут быть не должно)
AfterGroups = "dependent"
```

Что я делаю не правильно?

Код testng.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Default Suite">
  <test name="mts-sorm3-extractor-tests">
   <groups>
       <run>
           <include name="independent"/>
           <include name="dependent"/>
       </run>
    </groups>
    <classes>
      <class name="ru.mts.sorm.mts_sorm3_extractor_tests.Sorm3ExtractDictTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- mts-sorm3-extractor-tests -->
</suite> <!-- Custom suite -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всегда будут выполняться after и before методы обеих групп. Независимо от проходимых тестов.
Возможные решения:
1. Отказаться от специфических методов для каждой группы.
2. Раскидать тесты в разные классы.